# Correct typing of object with type Record<'row', number> when created in a Typescript function

Tags: typescript, types

Is there a chance in Typescript to do something like

```js
function doo(key: string, value: number): Record<typeof key, number> {
  return { key: value } // <-- this is wrong already, as it does use the parameter
}
```

such that I can use

```js
const a: Record<'row', number> = doo('row', 10);
```

There are several things here that don't work, yet basically I would like to call a function with a string constant as parameter, say `row`, such that the result is an object of type `Record<'row', ...>`. The two obstacles I have:

1. The function's parameter has to be typed such that it allows only constants known at compile time as parameters, since otherwise the compiler obviously cannot derive a compile time type for the result.
2. I can't seem to get the parameter's value as the key in the object literal.

I can create solutions with type casting and `any` in between, but is there a solution which avoids that?

Comment: Is [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WP7QKm) what you're looking for?  You need to use generics for the compiler and computed keys for runtime.

Comment: `Record<typeof key, number>` would be `Record<string, number>` since you already know `key` is `string`. No need for the runaround. Also `'row'` isn't a type, it's a value. Use `return { [key]: value }` for the internals of `doo`.

Answer (score 0):

Edit--------------

Complete the code.

But it seems typescript recognized `{ [key]: value }` as type `[x: string]: J`, so we have to do the type cast.

Any better solution without type cast is welcome.

```js
function doo<T extends string, J>(key: T, value: J) {
    return { [key]: value } as Record<T,J>
}

const a: Record<'row', number> = doo('row', 10);

const b: Record<'ooo', string> = doo('ooo', 'hello');
```

Original-------------

Is this what you want?

```js
declare function doo<T extends string, J>(key: T, value: J) : Record<T, J>;

const a: Record<'row', number> = doo('row', 10);

const b: Record<'ooo', string> = doo('ooo', 'hello');
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=5&ssc=54&pln=1&pc=1#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEAzArgOzAFwJYHtX2BxwB4AVeEADwxFWAGd56MYtUBzAGngCkA+ABQBrEAE8AXPFLcAblAjIQkngEp4kgErgcMYGW78A3AChjYPM3hRN23cQDkMHAHd73VMgC2AIxAw+8AC8BEQCji5u8ACMAAwqJmYWGPDeNuZ29kQ4kcysHAHBhDhhWZH2ABYgEBDZ8UA)

Comment: That would be it, ideally without type casts inside `doo`. Are you going to provide the answer here? Otherwise someone inevitably will downvote and flag as 'not-an-answer'. So far this is more for the comment section.